# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060032

Tags: android

I get this error i don't know why.  help me its give some resource error but i just copy project from net its work 100% fine when i create new project in Android Studio and just code paste all data its give me this error i dnt understand what is it. can any one tell me??

my logcat screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ6CL.jpg

```
 import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 public static Typeface sRobotoBlack;
 public static Typeface sRobotoBlackItalic;
 public static Typeface sRobotoLight;
 public static Typeface sRobotoLightItalic;
 public static Typeface sRobotoThin;

 private Toast mToast;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initTypefaces();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mToast != null) {
        mToast.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void makeToast(int resId) {
    makeToast(getString(resId));
}

public void makeToast(String text) {
    if (mToast == null) {
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } else {
        mToast.setText(text);
    }
    mToast.show();
}

private void initTypefaces() {
    if (sRobotoBlack == null) {
        sRobotoBlack = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
    }
    if (sRobotoBlackItalic == null) {
        sRobotoBlackItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");
    }
    if (sRobotoLight == null) {
        sRobotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    }
    if (sRobotoLightItalic == null) {
        sRobotoLightItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
    }
    if (sRobotoThin == null) {
        sRobotoThin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy the old `string.xml` in your `string.xml` under values folder

Comment: check aove i attech my screen shot on starting u can also see here http://imgur.com/uTdn2R7

Comment: i m not understand what u say? please give me solution what is a error?

Comment: The problem is in EasyTracker class could you upload the class code.

Comment: its in this jar file  libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar   buy wht its problem? i copy all fiels from previous project which i download from net. is work fine i just create new project and copy all this things

Comment: have u check this line?  makeToast(getString(resId));    i guesss problem is here may be

Comment: i update the answer, go to your string.xml in values folder and make sure if there is resId in there.

Comment: no there is no resId  string & i  copy all project files already